# Mozilla Builder editor unescaping Unicode characters, concurrent w. failed AMO uploads

Tags: javascript, firefox, unicode, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Having a devil of a time uploading latest revision of my Firefox add-on to AMO from builder.addons.mozilla.org.  Getting the "upload failed" message.  One thing that's different this revision is an escaped Unicode character in some HTML code used as the `content` property of a `widget` object.  The character unescapes in the online editor as soon as the string literal is closed with a closing quote.  The characters in the escape code are apparently included when the cursor column is calculated so the cursor is hovering a few spaces right of the rightmost character in the line.  Copying the affected text from the online editor to gedit (a plaintext editor) reveals the escape sequence, not the Unicode character.

```
var undo=widget.Widget({
  id:"cating",
  label:"undo most recent highlight",
  content:
   "<div style=\"height: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;\">&#8634;</div>",

...
```

Is the presence of an escaped character the reason for the failure to upload?  Is there a way to cause non-standard characters to display in HTML content and also be able to upload the add-on to AMO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the same issue as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790318

Comment: This is giving "upload failed", not "forbidden".